# How can I encode in base64 my instance ID

Tags: javascript, angular, security, serverless, faunadb

I need to encode my faunadb instance's id because I use it in an URL of this type
/mission/(id number)/team

I create instance with this:

```
/* code from functions/todos-create.js */
import faunadb from 'faunadb' /* Import faunaDB sdk */
/* configure faunaDB Client with our secret */
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

/* export our lambda function as named "handler" export */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /* parse the string body into a useable JS object */


  const eventBody = JSON.stringify(event.body)
  const data = JSON.parse(eventBody)
  const mission = {
    data: JSON.parse(data)
  }
  // {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}
  /* construct the fauna query */
  return client.query(q.Create(q.Ref("classes/missions"), mission))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("success", response)
    /* Success! return the response with statusCode 200 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    /* Error! return the error with statusCode 400 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  })
}
```

I call this lambda with a function in a service:

```
  createMission(data) {
    return fetch('/.netlify/functions/mission-create', {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
```

and then I load this at the init of my page with adress '/mission/(id number)/team' :

```
this._missionService.readById(this.route.snapshot.params.missionId)
```

with this lambda by a service again:

```
import faunadb from 'faunadb'

const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const id = event.path.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[0];
  console.log(`Function 'mission-read' invoked. Read id: ${id}`)
  return client.query(q.Get(q.Ref(q.Class("missions"), id)))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("success", response)
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  })
}
```

Actually this is not secure because url handling with id number is possible to access all my missions.
I want to encode in base64 this id, but I don't know how to do this, I begin in dev and I thought first encrypt id in service and decrypt it in service but someone said me front is not secure, then I want to use base64 in back.
Thanks for advice !

Comment: Hi! I am not sure exactly what it is you are asking. Ignoring the code, or maybe using some psuedo code could you clarify what your goals are? Something like: Given a fauna ref I'd like to be able to access it via a URL schema that looks like /xyz/:foo/bar with these security properties. Base64 isn't encryption or access control, so I'm not sure what role it plays here.

Comment: Huuumm, Given my custom url of type '/mission/123456/team' where '123456' is a fauna ref of an instance, I want to secure my url because visitor can easily access to my others instance of mission just by changing ref number, like 'mission/12345678/mission', then a friend said me to use base64 in my back-end for securise that.
But I never do this, I don't have knowledge or any idea

Comment: I see. Then you don't want base64 either. Because I can then trivially do base64(some other id) too. You want the property that only urls that you have given out lead back to an instance. You don't want your urls to be enumerable. You have a couple of choices: if you want them to be accessible without auth then you need encryption or signing, or you can add in access control and then enumeration doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this problem is definitely **not** to obfuscate the id with base64 (*which will protect nothing*), but instead you need to associate a user id with your sensitive information in the database.

You then can have them authenticate against your auth/data service to establish identity.  Then the service will only serve them records that are associated to them.

The tricky part of this solution is writing an auth protocol for your lambda services.